# Can I re-attach a detached QProcess?

Tags: windows, qt, scp

I have started a `QProcess` using `startDetached()`. Is there a way to re-attach it to this old or a new instance of `QProcess`? I want to be able to use `waitForFinished()` and other member functions.

It is not possible to use `start()` (i.e. to not detach it) because I run `scp.exe` without SSH keys.